# Pandas groupby: sum up the different values & keep the common ones

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to group the table below by Name then:

- Do the sum up the Quantity column
- Take the common value for Price, Exchange Rate & Currency.

[image]

I was wondering what's the best way to do this?

Here's what I tried:

```
quantity_col = position_trade_df.groupby("Name").sum()['Quantity']
position_trade_df = position_trade_df.drop('Quantity', axis =1).drop_duplicates()
position_trade_df.set_index("Name", inplace=True)
position_trade_df['Quantity'] = quantity_col
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  You're taking the sum of the quantity, and can use max on the rest since all the values will be the same within the group.

```
output = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Quantity':'sum','Price':'max','Exchange Rate':'max','Currency':'max'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great - learned something new.
Thing is, I have lots of columns and not just what's in the picture. How can I deal with that?

Comment: @Abdennour Feel free to upvote and mark as the accepted answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Chris, I've edited my comment & I'm not sure if you saw it. I have lots of columns, any idea how I can deal with that?

Comment: @Abdennour I edited my answer I, does it not solve the problem?